# Cannot bootstrap on MAAS due to invalid information for a node

Tags: juju, maas

Hello I have trying to bootstrap maas but when I do, I got this error

```
ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: cannot start bootstrap instance: getInstanceNetworkInterfaces failed: invalid hardware information for node "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-b011e814-c03b-11e4-a4c1-000c29d325ab/"
```

I have juju installed in the same server where I installed the MAAS server, the packages I installed was :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju-core

juju generate-config
```

and the `~/.juju/environments.yaml` config file :

```
  maas-server: 'http://172.16.190.128/MAAS/'
        admin-secret: asecurepassword
        authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
        # maas-oauth holds the OAuth credentials from MAAS.
        #
        maas-oauth: 'Gx83npf5wz7ByDmgkf:83YmU3LAp8EtEvE6CS:2r2pjxE8ragkuVPdXbLH$
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a known issue - https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1427814
The missing information is not critical for Juju and it shouldn't abort bootstrapping when this happens. We're planning on resolving this issue for the 15.05 release.

You could try recommissioning the node in question (node-b011e814-c03b-11e4-a4c1-000c29d325ab) from the MAAS web UI and it should solve your problem.